# Robotframework Serial library not throwing error or exception when unable to open serial port

Tags: robotframework

I am using Serial Library in robot framework like this

```
Library           SerialLibrary
```

If my serial port is already opened in minicom Robot framework is unable to read from that and its logical, but the library is not throwing any error exception to notify me, my serial port code looks like this

```
Open Serial Port
    [Arguments]    ${EXPECTED_PORT}
    Add Port   ${EXPECTED_PORT}
    ...        baudrate=115200
    ...        bytesize=8
    ...        parity=N
    ...        stopbits=1
    ...        timeout=999

Close Serial Port
    Delete All Ports
```

Am i missing to add something?